# ZXing Xamarin forms white background on IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, barcode-scanner, zxing.net

We have a problem with the ZXing Barcodescanner for Xamarin.Forms.
The scanner works perfectly on Android, but on IOS I can't see the camera image (preview). The scanner does scan barcodes on IOS if I hold them in front of the camera but the camera preview is just a white background.

I tried playing around with the options but without luck.
We are using Prism.Forms for MVVM.

As I mentioned, my code works well on android. 
Here are some details:

- The permissions are properly set on both platforms.
- The NuGets ZXing.Net.Mobile and ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms are added too
  all three projects (Android, IOS and portable)
- We are using .NET Standard 2.0
- Xamarin.Forms is version 3.4.0

**ScannerView.xaml**

```
<forms:ZXingScannerPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"
                    x:Class="App.Portable.View.ScannerView">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <forms:ZXingScannerView x:Name="scanner" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                IsScanning="{Binding IsScanning}"
                                IsAnalyzing="{Binding IsAnalyzing}"
                                Result="{Binding Result, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                ScanResultCommand="{Binding CmdScanResult}"
                                Options="{Binding ScannerOptions}"
        />

        <forms:ZXingDefaultOverlay Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                   TopText="Some title"
                                   ShowFlashButton="False"
                                   BottomText="Some bottom text"
                                   Opacity="0.9"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**ScannerViewModel.cs**

```
public class ScannerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //Initializing variables

    public ScannerViewModel()
    {
        var options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
        options.TryHarder = true;
        options.InitialDelayBeforeAnalyzingFrames = 300;
        options.DelayBetweenContinuousScans = 100;
        options.DelayBetweenAnalyzingFrames = 200;
        options.AutoRotate = false;

        ScanningOptions = options;
        Title = "Barcode-Scanner";
        CmdScanResult = new DelegateCommand(OnCmdScanResult);
        IsScanning = true;
        IsAnalyzing = true;
    }

    public MobileBarcodeScanningOptions ScanningOptions
    {
        get => _scanningOptions;

        set => SetProperty(ref _scanningOptions, value);
    }

    public bool IsScanning
    {
        get => _isScanning;

        set => SetProperty(ref _isScanning, value);
    }

    public bool IsAnalyzing
    {
        get => _isAnalyzing;

        set => SetProperty(ref _isAnalyzing, value);
    }

    public Result Result
    {
        get => _result;

        set => SetProperty(ref _result, value);
    }

    public DelegateCommand CmdScanResult { get; }

    private void OnCmdScanResult()
    {
        IsAnalyzing = false;
        IsScanning = false;
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
            async () =>
                {
                    IsAnalyzing = false;

                    var parameters = new NavigationParameters();
                    parameters.Add(CodeConstants.BARCODE, Result);
                    await NavigationService.GoBackAsync(parameters);
                });
    }
}
```

Does anyone see an issue at my code or has some suggestions on how to do it better or at least get it to work?

EDIT:
I uploaded a Testproject to my repo to reproduce the error. The Scanner works on iPhone but doesn't show the camera preview:
https://gitlab.com/mitti2000/zxingtest

Comment: Though it works fine on Android .I don't think the cause is your code .Did you add privacy in info.plist?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT  Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean with "privacy". I have this in my info.plist
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Camera permission needed for Barcode-Scanner</string>

Comment: Can you share your sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .And don't forget to remove your personal info .

Comment: I need some time but I'll create a sample that you can test.

Comment: Did you [initialize](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) the plugin in iOS-specific code?   
In your AppDelegate's FinishedLaunching (..) implementation, call:   

ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();

Comment: Yes I did, otherwise, the iOS would't scan. The issue is, that I dont' see the camera image...

Comment: I added a link to a repo to reproduce the problem. See Edit

Comment: I can’t get your sample repo to run

Comment: Try to re-add the nuget-packages. I use a different Package Source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:** You put the **ZXingScannerView** and **ZXingDefaultOverlay** in the same cell of grid .Then you set the `HorizontalOptions` of  **ZXingScannerView** as `EndAndExpand` .

**Solution:**

```
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
```